# How to compress a multi dimentional dataframe into a single column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, concatenation, nonetype

I have the following dataframe:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0   Twitter (True 01/21/2015)   None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
1   Google, Inc. (True 11/07/2016)  None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
2   Microsoft, (True 07/01/2016)    Facebook (True 11/01/2016)  None    None    None    None    None    None    None
3   standard & poors, Inc. (True 11/08/2016)    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
8   apple (True 11/10/2016)     apple (True 11/01/2016)     None    None    None    None    None    apple (True 11/01/2016)     None
```

How can I compress the above dataframe into a single dataframe?:

```
    0 
0   Twitter (True 01/21/2015)
1   Google, Inc. (True 11/07/2016)
2   Microsoft, (True 07/01/2016) \ Facebook (True 11/01/2016)
3   standard & poors, Inc. (True 11/08/2016) \ 
8   apple (True 11/10/2016) \ apple (True 11/01/2016) \ apple (True 11/01/2016)
```

I tried to:

```
df = df.iloc[:,0].join('\')
```

However, I do not understand how to add a separator. How should I compress the dataframe with a separator character?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) `None` to `NaN` and then remove `NaN` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), last [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply` `join`:

```
df = df.replace({None: np.nan, 'None': np.nan}).stack()
df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(' \\ '.join)
print (df)
0                            Twitter (True 01/21/2015)
1                       Google, Inc. (True 11/07/2016)
2    Microsoft, (True 07/01/2016) \ Facebook (True ...
3             standard & poors, Inc. (True 11/08/2016)
8    apple (True 11/10/2016) \ apple (True 11/01/20...
dtype: object
```

Another solution with list comprehension:

```
df = df.replace({None: np.nan, 'None': np.nan})
#python 3 use str, python 2 basestring
df = df.apply(lambda x : ' \\ '.join([y for y in x if isinstance(y, str)]), axis=1)

print (df)
0                            Twitter (True 01/21/2015)
1                       Google, Inc. (True 11/07/2016)
2    Microsoft, (True 07/01/2016) \ Facebook (True ...
3             standard & poors, Inc. (True 11/08/2016)
8    apple (True 11/10/2016) \ apple (True 11/01/20...
dtype: object
```

**Timings**:

```
#[50000 rows x 9 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [43]: %timeit (df.replace({None: np.nan, 'None': np.nan}).apply(lambda x : ''.join([y for y in x if isinstance(y, str)]), axis=1))
1 loop, best of 3: 820 ms per loop

In [44]: %timeit (df.replace({None: np.nan, 'None': np.nan}).stack().groupby(level=0).apply(' \\ '.join))
1 loop, best of 3: 4.62 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks but, I got a weird format. Each character goes down.

Comment: Which is faster?... I noted that the first solution takes a little bit

Comment: Yes, faster is solution with list comprehension, because there is no reshape.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (I get the following output with a small dataframe which seems ok):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0':['Twitter (True 01/21/2015)', 'Google, Inc. (True 11/07/2016)', ' Microsoft, (True 07/01/2016)'], '1':[None, None, 'Facebook  (True 11/01/2016)'], '2':[None, None, None]})
df = df.replace({None: ' ', 'None': ' '})
df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: '\\'.join(x), axis=1)


0                        Twitter (True 01/21/2015)\ \ 
1                   Google, Inc. (True 11/07/2016)\ \ 
2     Microsoft, (True 07/01/2016)\Facebook  (True ...
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks I got a weird format. All the characters are down splited .

Comment: how does your output look like?

Comment: `l i k e  t h i s`